# Python send a request to a web service which expects 3 headers, payload (multipart/formdata) , uploadfile(Content-Type: application/octet-stream)

Tags: python, curl

Python code to send a request to web service which expects 3 parameters , 3 headers(including a session id returned by another webservice , two other parameters),  payload data 6-7 text fields(multipart/formdata) , a file to be uploaded(Content-Type: application/octet-stream).

MIME I got while trying through rest client is like :

```
Content-Length=2059827
session_id=123
tent_id=123
status_id=123
Content-Type=multipart/form-data; boundary=--8d147115358844c

--8d147115358844c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="app_id"

7xx
--8d147115358844c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="app_detail_id"

4xxx
--8d147115358844c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="device_id"

testxx
--8d147115358844c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="app_id"

1.x.x
--8d147115358844c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="min_id"

8.x.x
--8d147115358844c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bxx_id"

com.xxx.xxxtest
--8d147115358844c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rel"

gxxxxs
--8d147115358844c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xxx"

9x.x
--8d147115358844c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="disablei"

0
--8d147115358844c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="enabledvd"

1
--8d147115358844c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="enable_odd"

1
--8d147115358844c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xxxrap"

1
--8d147115358844c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="app_xxx"; filename="app-xxx.apk"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

PK   GwJAv�h�Y�  ��    META-INF/MANIFEST.MF��ǲ�ڶ6�?�N�*�{@�?� �F���{���\i�2)O�]���2'0��~�'+�|�i�W��&*��������׶���s�����������E�e��{�;�����_�y��ߵ׀�E20���?c��Ͽ.;r�
--8d147115358844c--
```

I have tried through CURL through shellscript to create the mime but the server send invalid input error:

`curl "https://xxxxx.xxxxx.com/File.svc/Updateserver" -H "appstore_session_id: xxxxx" -H "source: 0" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7BIf8ODIJyIA" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Cookie: _ga=GA1.x.xx.xx; __utma=x75.8x.1x.x; __utmc=8xx; __utmz=xx.1xxxxx.x.x.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not"%"20provided); ASP.NET_SessionId=xxxx" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "tenant_id: 1" --data-binary "@mime.txt" --data-binary "@app-445.exe" --data-binary "----WebKitFormBoundary7BIf8ODIJyIA--"`

I have tried python code from this site for python:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578846-composing-a-postable-http-request-with-multipartfo/
as I am anew to python iam not able to generate the MIME output I wanted. please help(sorry for the length of the question:|)

Comment: Don't set the content type header yourself nor add in boundaries. Leave `multipart/form-data` encoding to curl instead.

Comment: Thanku for your reply. Without setting the boundary and content header how can i differentiate b/w various text fields in form while passing it using curl command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code working perfectly:

`curl -H "session_id:$session_id" -H "tnant_id: 4" -H "source: 4.x" --insecure -i -F "app_id=2.3" -F "app_detail_id=$app_detail_id" -F "device_type=Phones" -F "app_version=$app_version" -F "min_compatible_os_version=4.x.x" -F "bundle_identifier=com.xxxxx.test" -F "release_notes=test" -F "app_status=test" -F "disableiTunes=0" -F "enablelocalstorage=1" -F "enable_sso=1" -F "app_binary=@app-6.apk" "https://xxx.testing.com/server/Updateserver" > op.txt`

This uploads the file "app-6.apk" perfectly to the site.

NB: any file extention can be uploaded

Thanks you @Martijn Pieters